# Cumulative count of unique IDs per date

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have the following DF:

```
Date          ID   
2019-06-01    A
2019-06-01    B
2019-06-01    B
2019-06-02    A
2019-06-02    C
2019-06-03    C
2019-06-03    A
```

What's is the most pythonic way to get the cumulative count of unique ids per date as:

```
Date          ID   
2019-06-01    2
2019-06-02    3
2019-06-03    3
```

I could use a for loop by date and using `np.isin` but that's terrible performance-wise.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us do

```
s = df.groupby('Date')['ID'].agg(list).cumsum()
s = s.map(lambda x : len(set(x))).reset_index()
s
         Date  ID
0  2019-06-01   2
1  2019-06-02   3
2  2019-06-03   3
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `groupby().nunique` with a `cumsum()`:

```
dates = pd.date_range(df.Date.min(), df.Date.max())

(df.drop_duplicates(['ID'])
   .groupby('Date')['ID'].nunique().cumsum()
   .reindex(dates).ffill()
)
```

OUtput:

```
2019-06-01    2.0
2019-06-02    3.0
2019-06-03    3.0
Freq: D, Name: ID, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Somehow that's giving me wrong results. For example in my case: 
A = Day 1 uniques : size 40941. 
B = Day 2 uniques:size 28262. 
C = B[~np.isin(B,A)] size 12114
then C+A = 53055
that code is giving me day 1 uniques: 3519 and day two: 5486